# component.get(v.myfield) returns undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Can someone help me to find where is the problem.
Il my controller:

```
({
    execute : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get('c.Myclass'); 
        var InvoiceNum = 'testInvoice';
        var InvoiceAcc =component.get('v.AccountId__c'); 
        action.setParams({
            "invoiceNumber" :InvoiceNum , "accountId" : InvoiceAcc
        });
        window.alert(InvoiceNum);
        window.alert(InvoiceAcc);
        action.setCallback(this, function(a){
            var state = a.getState(); // get the response state
            if(state == 'SUCCESS') {
                alert('Demande de mise \xe0 jour effectu\xe9e');
            }
            else{
                 txt = 'There was an error on this page.\n\n';
                 txt += 'Click OK to continue.\n\n';
                 window.alert(txt);
            }
        });
          window.setTimeout(
          $A.getCallback(function() {
          $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
        }), 1000
        );
          $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
})
```

the value of ***component.get('v.AccountId__c');*** returns "Undefined" even if my object has an account Id this doesn't work only in lightning

here is my .cmp :

```
<aura:component controller="Mymethod" >
        <aura:handler name='init' value='{!this}' action="{!c.execute}"/>
        <aura:set attribute="componentString" value="false"></aura:set>
        <div style="height: 6rem;">
        <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_large slds-spinner_brand">
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
            <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: There's no AccountId__c value specified. Where should this be coming from?

Comment: My opened object

Comment: I want to get my object AccountId :) , i don't know if it's clear for you

Comment: You'll need to use force:hasRecordId and force:recordData, then you can get the AccountId__c field from there.

Comment: I tried this and doesn't work too: component.get('v.Incoice__c.AccountId__c');

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to work. You need to load the data first.

Comment: Ok, thaks a lot for your return , but should i use force:hasRecordId and force:recordData in my .cmp?

Comment: I tried but doesn't work force:hasRecordId and force:recordData